# What value can I put for default in and OpenApiSchema?

Tags: c#, asp.net, openapi, swashbuckle

I am trying to add an optional parameter to my API endpoint. The default value of this parameter is "true". I am getting an error saying cannot convert bool to OpenAPIAny. What other value could I put besides that?

```
operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter()
{
    Name = "Name",
    In = ParameterLocation.Query,
    Description = "Description",
    Required = false,
    Schema = new OpenApiSchema
    {
        Type = "boolean",
        Default = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Default` property is a type of IOpenApiAny so you will need to convert the boolean to that. Try using this line:

```
Default = new Microsoft.OpenApi.Any.OpenApiBoolean(true)
```